# Tags vs TagNames in OData

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

This query works on odata.stackexchange.com

```
select Tags from Posts
```

[Try it yourself](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/15307/)

Yet, if you access OData endpoint like this:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/atom/Posts

... you can see that Tags field mysteriously has became TagNames field:

```
<d:TagNames>&lt;c#&gt;&lt;math&gt;</d:TagNames>
```

Do you know why? Is it a different database?

Comment: +1 Nice find. I think this is probably a bug in the OData endpoint. At a guess, they missed remapping the field from "TagNames" to "Tags".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've pushed what I think should be a fix for this:
https://code.google.com/r/jseigelis-test/source/detail?r=2faea6ff20645541959c6c4b6ad9867f64bdf4a5

I say "should be" because I was unable to test -- IIS7 can't be installed on XP here at home. I know you've been making some changes -- if you are able to test, grab these changes into your own clone and make sure it works before we flag down @waffles to push this into the trunk.

**Edit:** The fix is now live.

Comment: Thank you Jon. I pulled your change and it works! I believe you can now request a merge.

Comment: By the way, I managed to get it working under Cassini by using raw URLs and commenting out lines with `IncomingMessageProperties`.

Comment: @Pavel: Oh, perfect. That's good to know. Thanks for testing. I sent Sam (aka waffles) an e-mail requesting a merge.